# Is this proof by S. Lang wrong (Real and Functional analysis)?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation

In p.339 of Real and functional analysis (S. Lang) the Lemma 3.3 states

> **Lemma 3.3**: If $f$ is a differentiable map on an interval $[a,b]$ whose derivative is $0$, then $f$ is constant.

Lang gives the following proof

> **Proof**: Suppose that $f(t)\neq f(a)$ for some $t\in [a,b]$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, let $\lambda$ be a functional such that $\lambda(f(t))\neq \lambda (f(a))$. The map $\lambda \circ f$ is differentiable and its derivative is $0$. Hence $\lambda \circ f$ is constant on $[a,b]$, contradiction.

Here I get everything up to the last sentence, I cannot help thinking that this proof is wrong. Since there is no presented argument in why should the map $\lambda \circ f$ be constant. It seems as if there was some kind of mistake, here. Or is there something else here that I am not aware of?

Comment: What's the domain of $f$? Where does it take its values?

Comment: It is not actually specified, but the context  of the book is to generalize derivatives in Banach spaces, but he talks about an interval, which only make sense in ordered spaces, I take that $f:\mathbb{R}\supseteq [a,b]\rightarrow F$ for some topological normed vector spaces which is complete (Banach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is to reduce the problem to a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the author is
taking for granted that the mean value theorem applies here.

Since you have $f: \mathbb{B} \to \mathbb{R}$, you cannot apply the usual mean value theorem. However, if you can show that $\phi(f(x)-f(y)) = 0$ for all $\phi \in \mathbb{B}^*$, then you know that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Since the well known mean value theorem applies to $\phi \circ f$, we are finished.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\lambda\circ f$ is a differentiable function from $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R$ and whose derivative is $0$ everywhere, $\lambda\circ f$ is constant. This is a well known corollary from the mean value theorem.

Comment: But he introduces the Mean value theorem in the next page.

Comment: Do you mean the mean value theorem for real valued functions?

Comment: No, I mean the mean value theorem for vector spaces.

Comment: Then there is no problem in using the mean value theorem for real valued functions.